# An exception occured in driver: could not find driver tying to create database on doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I've executed

```
 php bin/console doctrine:database:create
```

to create the project's datbabase andI get this error

```
Failed loading /opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/xdebug.so:  /opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/xdebug.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

In AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 115:

  An exception occured in driver: could not find driver  


In PDOConnection.php line 47:

  could not find driver  


In PDOConnection.php line 43:

  could not find driver
```

I'm using  xampp on ubuntu and this is the config file of symfony

```
 # This file is auto-generated during the composer install
parameters:
    database_host: 127.0.0.1
    database_port: 3306
    database_name: mydb
    database_user: root
    database_password: 12345
    mailer_transport: smtp
    mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
    mailer_user: null
    mailer_password: null
    secret: 55c7fcc15002180af1c4f7ad79dc62cfe6dfd91e
```

I'dont know what is wrong

Comment: You don't have the proper driver enabled what is you configuration ?

Comment: default configuration pdo is enabled

Answer (score 1):

I think the driver is not configured in your parameter, so let's add it like :

```html
parameters:
    database_driver: pdo_mysql # <== you can change it in your driver database
    database_host: 127.0.0.1
    database_port: 3306
    database_name: mydb
    database_user: root
    database_password: 12345
    mailer_transport: smtp
    mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
    mailer_user: null
    mailer_password: null
    secret: 55c7fcc15002180af1c4f7ad79dc62cfe6dfd91e
```

NB: you can check all driver available in your terminal like this:

```html
php -m
```

and normally it must display you the extension driver you need like :

```html
.......
PDO
pdo_dblib
pdo_mysql
PDO_ODBC
pdo_pgsql
pdo_sqlite
pgsql
.......
```

thanks, I hope it's help you